# display multiple images from gallery in gridview using Fishbun library in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm trying to select multiple images from gallery and display it in gridview using this [Library](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun) as well get path for each image so I can save the in database..my issue is when I select images that I want They don't appear in gridview..I trying to use breakpoints to debug code but still not clear for me what goes wrong

here is my code
**Myfragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_venue_imges, container, false);
    gvGallery = view.findViewById(R.id.mygrid);
    selectImage = view.findViewById(R.id.uploadimageButton0);
    selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FishBun.with(getActivity()).setImageAdapter(new PicassoAdapter())
                    .setMaxCount(5)
                    .setMinCount(1)
                    .startAlbum();
    });

   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FishBun.FISHBUN_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //   path = imageData.getStringArrayListExtra(FishBun.INTENT_PATH);
            // you can get an image path(ArrayList<String>) on <0.6.2

            mArrayUri = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(FishBun.INTENT_PATH);


            for (int i = 0; i < mArrayUri.size(); i++) {
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(mArrayUri.get(i).getPath());
                mArrayUri.add(uri);

                myAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),mArrayUri);
                gvGallery.setAdapter(myAdapter);
               // myAdapter.addToList(uri);
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private int pos;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri;

    public ImageAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mArrayUri = mArrayUri;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArrayUri.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mArrayUri.get(position);
    }
    void addToList(Uri uriPath)
    {
        this.mArrayUri.add(uriPath);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  
        View view = convertView;

        ViewHolder holder;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.images_item, null);
            //view = ctx.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.images_item, null);
            holder.mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Gallery);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(ctx.getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(position));
            try {
                bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ctx.getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(position));
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

            return view;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            private ImageView  mImageView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you send FISHBUN_REQUEST_CODE on FishBun to start gallery also INTENT_PATH in onActivityResult ? @lolo

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my query that OnActivityResult not called so that's why nothing is displayed in gridview [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/10015540) was helpful for this issue